# Convert string (without any separator) to list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a phone number(string), e.g. "+123-456-7890", that I want to turn into a list that looks like: [+, 1, 2, 3, -, ...., 0].

Why? So I can go iterate through the list and remove all the symbols, so I'm left with a list of only digits, which I can then convert back to a string.

What's the best way to solve this problem? None of the solutions I've come across are applicable, because I don't have any special characters in-between the digits (so I can't split the string there.)

Any ideas? I really appreciate it!

Edit - this is what I've tried:

```
x = row.translate(None, string.digits)
list = x.split()
```

Also:

```
filter(lambda x: x isdigit())
```

Comment: As an aside -- Generally, we expect users to show code that they've tried.  This is a pretty simple problem, so seeing what you've tried (and what failed) may help us to help you understand the language better (rather than just giving you an answer and sending you on your way with no real tools for solving the next problem)

Comment: Ok - I've added what I had tried. I didn't think it was relevant so I didn't post it initially

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking for.  I've changed my downvote to an upvote as those seem like reasonable attempts.

Comment: @nv39 So you are figuring out which solutions to prefer. mgilson, uptownnickbrown, tur1ng, and Kabie have working solutions. My preferences are mgilson for using generator + join; Kabie for join plus filter (prefer generator to filter); tur1ng for regular expression (not really complex enough to warrant regex); uptownnickbrown for iteration and string append (works but not preferred python idiom). That's the way I see them, anyway -- purely as style issues. I doubt that there is any speed issue to be considered here.

Comment: @nv39 You can look at a few time measurements in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15527809/1974792)

Comment: @nv39, btw the `row.translate(None, '+-')` appears to be the fastest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean that you want something like:

```
''.join(n for n in phone_str if n.isdigit())
```

This uses the fact that strings are iterable.  They yield 1 character at a time when you iterate over them.

---

Regarding your efforts,

This one actually *removes* all of the digits from the string leaving you with only non-digits.

```
x = row.translate(None, string.digits)
```

This one splits the string on runs of whitespace, not after each character:

```
list = x.split()
```

Comment: First one does not work, I get the string back and not a python list. Is there [] missing?

Comment: I was addressing the "which I can then convert back to a string." part of OP's question.  If you just want a list of the numbers from 0-9, you can do:  `[n for n in phone_str if n.isdigit()]` or something similar (depending on whether you want a list of characters or a list of `int`).

Answer (score 61):

Make a **list(your_string)**.

```
>>> s = "mep"
>>> list(s)
['m', 'e', 'p']
```

Answer (score 6):

```
''.join(filter(str.isdigit, "+123-456-7890"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it works!  There's a few answers here, so I'm trying to figure out what the best way to do it is. Can you tell me if/why this way of doing it is better than the answer given by tur1ng? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the re module:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\D', '', '+123-456-7890')
```

This will replace all non-digits with ''.

Comment: thanks for your answer - it works well. Can you tell me why this answer is better than the one given by mgilson? They both work... I'm trying to figure out which one is better/why

Comment: It *may* be faster than the generator, but I doubt it.  You can speed up the generator solution by using a list-comprehension as well but that's not particularly "pythonic".  Ultimately, I prefer the list-comp/generator because anyone can read it.  Even if you didn't know there was a `str.isdigit` function, you can probably guess how it works.  With this one, your reader needs at least a basic knowledge of regex which isn't something you can always assume.

Comment: @mgilson No doubt about the cryptic nature of `regex`. Ultimately a question like "which one is better?" can't actually be answered. The solutions are different.

Comment: This did a bit faster if you compile the regex. Tested.

Comment: @Kabie -- Faster than what?  Faster than it was previously or faster than another solution?  Also, how did you test?

Comment: @mgilson: Faster than `filter/generator` + `isdigit`. Test with `timeit`.

Comment: @Kabie -- Yep.  I can reproduce that.  I'm actually a little surprised.  The regex engine did a good job on this one :)

Comment: @mgilson: The `str.isdigit` is even slower than `'0123456789'.__contains__`. I guess it's because it checks unicode chars.

Comment: @mgilson you can check some numbers in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15527809/1974792)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has been answered, but just to point out what `timeit` has to say about the solutions efficiency. Using these parameters:

```
size = 30
s = [str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(size)] + (size/3) * ['-']
random.shuffle(s)
s = ''.join(['+'] + s)
timec = 1000
```

That is the "phone number" has 30 digits, 1 plus sing and 10 '-'. I've tested these approaches:

```
def justdigits(s):
    justdigitsres = ""
    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit():
            justdigitsres += str(char)
    return justdigitsres

re_compiled = re.compile(r'\D')

print('Filter: %ss' % timeit.Timer(lambda : ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, s))).timeit(timec))
print('GE: %ss' % timeit.Timer(lambda : ''.join(n for n in s if n.isdigit())).timeit(timec))
print('LC: %ss' % timeit.Timer(lambda : ''.join([n for n in s if n.isdigit()])).timeit(timec))
print('For loop: %ss' % timeit.Timer(lambda : justdigits(s)).timeit(timec))
print('RE: %ss' % timeit.Timer(lambda : re.sub(r'\D', '', s)).timeit(timec))
print('REC: %ss' % timeit.Timer(lambda : re_compiled.sub('', s)).timeit(timec))
print('Translate: %ss' % timeit.Timer(lambda : s.translate(None, '+-')).timeit(timec))
```

And came out with these results:

```
Filter: 0.0145790576935s
GE: 0.0185861587524s
LC: 0.0151798725128s
For loop: 0.0242128372192s
RE: 0.0120108127594s
REC: 0.00868797302246s
Translate: 0.00118899345398s
```

Apparently GEs and LCs are still slower than a regex or a compiled regex. And apparently my CPython 2.6.6 didn't optimize the string addition that much. `translate` appears to be the fastest (which is expected as the problem is stated as "ignore these two symbols", rather than "get these numbers" and I believe is quite low-level).

And for `size = 100`:

```
Filter: 0.0357120037079s
GE: 0.0465779304504s
LC: 0.0428011417389s
For loop: 0.0733139514923s
RE: 0.0213229656219s
REC: 0.0103371143341s
Translate: 0.000978946685791s
```

And for `size = 1000`:

```
Filter: 0.212141036987s
GE: 0.198996067047s
LC: 0.196880102158s
For loop: 0.365696907043s
RE: 0.0880808830261s
REC: 0.086804151535s
Translate: 0.00587010383606s
```

Comment: Note that the regex is only compiled the first time.  All the other times, `re` will use the cached version so you only have an extra dictionary lookup.  A vast majority of the timing difference there is probably because of the first compiling.

Comment: @mgilson You mean for the `RE` test? I've tried it with one iteration of `timeit` and a quite big string. The ratio between `RE` and `REC` times are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try list(x)??

```
 y = '+123-456-7890'
 c =list(y)
 c
```

['+', '1', '2', '3', '-', '4', '5', '6', '-', '7', '8', '9', '0']

Comment: Please read other answers before replying. You are repeating one.

Answer (score 2):

A python string *is* a list of characters.  You can iterate over it right now!

```
justdigits = ""
for char in string:
    if char.isdigit():
        justdigits += str(char)
```

Comment: This will create a bunch of strings (`'1'`, `'12'`, and so on), which is plain unnecessary.

Comment: @DJV: Actually, CPython optimizes that. If only one reference to a string object exists, as is the case here, `+=` grows the string in place.

Comment: @kindall It still is slower than anything else though.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't optimize this at all, just broke it down in simple terms to illustrate to the OP how easy it is to iterate over strings.  I think @mgilson's approach is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of converting to a list, you could just iterate over the first string and create a second string by adding each of the digit characters you find to that new string.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `str.translate`, you just have to give it the right arguments:

```
>>> dels=''.join(chr(x) for x in range(256) if not chr(x).isdigit())
>>> '+1-617-555-1212'.translate(None, dels)
'16175551212'
```

N.b.: This won't work with unicode strings in Python2, or at all in Python3. For those environments, you can create a custom class to pass to `unicode.translate`:

```
>>> class C:
...    def __getitem__(self, i):
...       if unichr(i).isdigit():
...          return i
... 
>>> u'+1-617.555/1212'.translate(C())
u'16175551212'
```

This works with non-ASCII digits, too:

```
>>> print u'+\u00b9-\uff1617.555/1212'.translate(C()).encode('utf-8')
¹６175551212
```